# Blender union boolean modifier acts oddly

Tags: union, blender, modifier

I'm trying to model a low poly cicada with Blender in order to 3D print it. I have the body and I would like to make a union (Boolean modifier) with wings. Unfortunately this Boolean modifier makes the body disappear and makes appear two strange polys.

I've checked the normals orientation and non manifold vertices, they seem ok. I could not find any solution out there as most common problem with Boolean modifiers is execution problem which is not the case here.

I should say that I've unfortunately created the first wing in the same object as body (using create cube in body's edit mode) then extracted it using p>>separate by loose parts. This may explain the odd behavior of the modifier but I don't know how to solve it.

Please find the file here : [my cicada file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6T-Ri4Rk5LmakxEeVMxVTE3ZEU/view?usp=sharing), hope it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the hollow body. If you remove the inside shell or create a hole between the two mesh pieces the boolean works.

If you want to 3d print this model you will most likely need to add a hole to allow material from the inside to drain out. [This shapeways tutorial](http://www.shapeways.com/tutorials/creating-hollow-objects) explains making hollow shapes.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I have not done it before because I wanted to : 1) apply the solidify modifier to the body only (and avoid problems with thin wings) and 2) make a hole after the union with the wings to have the position of the center of mass. I will find a way.
Thanks a lotagain for your help.